# R loop long data return minimum and cumulative values

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, cumulative-sum

[Here is a link to my data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i79auckwodvd1du/stackoverflow%20example.csv?dl=0). It looks like this:

```
year    cars    company
1975    11.75   chevy
1976    19.71   chevy
1977    21.23   chevy
1978    11.00   chevy
1979    8.26    chevy
1980    8.63    chevy
1981    19.09   chevy
1982    30.52   chevy
1983    27.51   chevy
```

I'd like to create two new variable columns:

1. year_first, which would return the first year a company is listed in the data (e.g. This would be "1975" for every "chevy" row)
2. cars_cumulative, which would return the cumulative total for all cars for a particular company produced up to that point

Thus, I'd like my data to look like this:

```
year    cars    company year_first  cars_cumulative
1975    11.75   chevy   1975        11.75
1976    19.71   chevy   1975        31.46
1977    21.23   chevy   1975        52.69
1978    11.00   chevy   1975        63.69
1979    8.26    chevy   1975        71.95
1980    8.63    chevy   1975        80.58
1981    19.09   chevy   1975        99.67
1982    30.52   chevy   1975        130.19
1983    27.51   chevy   1975        157.70
```

I imagine I should write a for loop? I'm just not sure the best way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following base R technique should work for a data.frame df:

```
df <- data.frame(year=1975:1983, 
                 cars=c(11.75, 19.71, 21.23, 11, 8.26, 8.63, 19.09, 30.52, 27.51), 
                 company=rep("chevy", length(1975:1983)))
# add variables
df$year_first <- ave(df$year, df$company, FUN=min)
df$cars_cumulative <- ave(df$cars, df$company, FUN=cumsum)
```

A nice addition mentioned by @rawr, is that these lines above can be wrapped in `within` which tells R to use the data.frame as the first point of reference:

```
within(df, {
  year_first <- ave(year, company, FUN=min)
  cars_cumulative <- ave(cars, company, FUN=cumsum)
})
```

The use of `within` not only saves the typing of many "df$" prefixes, which makes the code easier to read, but it also can help to organize your code, as you can put the creation of all of your additional variables into one code block.

If you are working with a very large dataset, or you like succinct code, you might take a look at `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, c("year_first", "cars_cumulative"):=list(min(year), cumsum(cars)), by="company"]
# or 
df[, `:=`(year_first = year[1L], cars_cumulative = cumsum(cars)), by=company]
```

or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 = df %>% group_by(company) %>% 
  mutate(year_first = first(year), cars_cumulative = cumsum(cars))
```

Comment: Let me take a first crack at the data.table method. If there are improvements, I'd be delighted to learn them.

Comment: This is perfect. Never knew about the ave function. Incredibly helpful. Thanks! @Frank

Comment: Looks good. Minor note: No need to `dt = setDT(df)` since the `set*` functions modify by reference.

Comment: @Frank I was aware of that great feature, but decided (for some reason) to keep the df and dt separate. It was probably the influence of squinting and scratching my head at the `data.table` FAQ and related intros for long periods of time. Thanks for the additional `:=` syntax.